# Concat multiple columns then splitting them - MySQL

Tags: mysql, split, concatenation

This is a really a two step process I need. I have a table that has 26 columns that look like this:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB   ColumnC  ColumnD  ColumnE  ColumnF

winter       0        0      summer   0        Dog

0          spring    fall      0      0        0

0            0        0      summer   car      0
```

I need to be able to Concat all the words in the columns into one column separated by a | but leaving out any zeros in other columns. The first row should look like this in column 27 **winter|summer|dog**. I then need to be able to separate the results in column 27 **winter|summer|dog** into column 28 winter, column 29 summer, column 20 dog

The results would look like this:

```
Column28    Column29    Column30

winter      summer      dog

spring      fall

summer      car
```

The program I am using doesn't allow me to use wildcards, so I need to take the 26 columns and dump them into 3 as the most a row has in any of the 26 columns is three words. I have 750,000 rows and the searches are taking forever.

There could be an easier way of just moving the first instance of not a 0 in any column into column 28, the second instance of not a zero in a row to column 29, etc. I also have a bunch of other columns before the 26 columns I posted above like name, phone, etc. that you should be aware of as you cant just say first none zero in a row to column 27.

Comment: Oh goodness..... is it of any help to you if I suggest a schema restructure? There is a crack in the foundation and it'll be a battle your whole life to keep the walls straight.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately I'm very new to this and trying to teach myself as I go along. The table I am working with way made by someone else before me and it's a complete mess.

Comment: maybe you can point me in the right direction. I don't mind reading up on stuff, but I have no idea where to look. lol

Comment: I'm not sure how deep in the rabbit whole you want to go (of database design). For me, it lit a fire which grew into a career, so I kinda love it... but I know it can be a lot more than folks want to bite off when they are simply trying to solve a problem. It can be complicated to get it right, but if you want a quality app it will be worth it to start sooner than later.

Comment: I'll compose some thoughts into an answer...

Answer (score 1):

(I'll post this as an answer instead of a comment because I think it's so important)

The only sustainable solution to this and the 27 other nasty queries you'd have to write this year is a better database design.

The concept you should peruse as a starting point is called "[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)", and it teaches you a way of modeling your domain within a set of rules and patterns which give you flexible storage (relatively) free from the pitfalls of designs like that in your OP (i.e. rows with only 10% useful data, columns with even less, radical bending of available tools to make anything useful happen).

The concepts can seem overwhelming (for example, [the book that got me started](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123735688) is 976 pages), but as principles, they can be brilliantly simple to demonstrate. And for that, I leave it to wikipedia as a decent starting point.

Basically, we have a system of "normal forms", which are kinda like "progress levels" for database designs. The first one ("first normal form" is the nomenclature) alone will work miracles for what you want to do with that data, and essentially gets you thinking about this: **what single atomic thing am I modeling with this table?**

I would normally provide a small example here, but wikipedia is so accessible, I'm sure you'll readily start absorbing from their article on [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Then, of course, you'll be interested in [second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) and [third](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) normal forms. As far as market trends, that's the point of diminishing returns (i.e. come back in a few years for higher forms). However, I'll reiterate that if you only learned solidly how to implement first normal form in your modeled domain, your life would be much better :-)

Once you get that established, you'll want to quickly brush up on SQL's `JOIN` concept, as these rules essentially break your domain into atomic pieces, and many of your tasks will start to require simple joins in your queries.

Good Luck!

Comment: Ah thanks!! That's a nice solution that I've seen in other database but didn't know how to do it. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Column27, '|', 1) AS Column28,
          replace(substring(substring_index(Column27, '|', 2), length(substring_index(Column27, '|', 1)) + 1), '|', '') AS Column29,
          replace(substring(substring_index(Column27, '|', 3), length(substring_index(Column27, '|', 2)) + 1), '|', '') AS Column30
FROM (SELECT *, CONCAT_WS('|', NULLIF(ColumnA, 0), NULLIF(ColumnB, 0), ..., NULLIF(ColumnZ, 0)) AS Column27
      FROM MyTable)
```